# Make a batch file run a python code with arguments

Tags: python, batch-file

how do I make a python code that runs a .bat (batch) file, and the .bat file
 calls another python with arguments?
I know that if you want to call a python file using .bat you need to write:

```
C:\python27\python.exe D:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX.py %*
```

what about arguments? I need this D:\XXX\XXX\XXX\XXX.py file to get args...
Thanks!

Comment: Is your problem passing arguments from the batch script, or receiving arguments in the Python script?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run a batch file from python program you should do the following

OS : Windows

run.py

```
import os
os.system("<bat_file_name> argument1 argument2 argument3")
```

In batch file

run.bat

```
echo %1
echo %2
echo %3
```

These will print all your 3 arguments.

In case you wanna excute a python script using batch

run.py

```
python run.py argument1 argument2 argument3
```

and In python file you will grab them as

```
import sys
arg1 = sys.argv[1]
arg1 = sys.argv[2]
arg1 = sys.argv[3]
```

Comment: Hi, I need to use check_input using subprocess. is it the same?

Comment: Not working... 
'bash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: you are on windows then run it without `bash`

Comment: I think you meant %1 , %2 ..  instead of $1 $2 .. no? because with % it works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("foo")
parser.add_argument("bar")
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.foo, args.bar)
```

Above code is a python code for simple argparse example. Name this as example.py

Your bat file should be like

```
C:\python27\python.exe D:\XXX\XXX\XXX\example.py hello world
```

A simple single line code.

Save this batch file as example.bat somewhere and execute this at the cmd window.

Comment: what is the "hello world" after the .py for?

Comment: those are the two arguments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers!

if you want to get arguments from python to batch,
you simply pass them one by one with space in between, for example:

```
output = subprocess.check_output("abc.bat "+ arg1 + " " + arg2)
```

and to use them in the batch file:

```
%1 - for the first argument
%2 - for the second argument
%3 - for the third argument
```

and so forth.

Thanks :)